# Apex CRUD Violation

Tags: apex, pmd

```
if(Schema.sObjectType.SchemeMaster__c.fields.InterestRate__c.isAccessible() && Schema.sObjectType.PromotionMaster__c.fields.Name.isAccessible())
{
                    sObj = [select name ,   InterestRate__c , MonthDueDate__c ,(SELECT Id,Name from Promotion_Masters__r) from SchemeMaster__c where id =: lObj.Scheme__c];
                    autoMap.put('SchemeMaster__c', sObj);
}
```

This is still giving me an `ApexCRUDViolation`.

Comment: Within your subset of code, you're only checking if field is visible. Based on your scenario you should also check object level accessibility, that's where the security check is complaining about.

Comment: @RahulSharma Why not add that as an answer?

Comment: @AdrianLarson, have not added it as an answer as this could be one of many cause of the error. if you think this is answer worthy, will add it. thanks

Comment: I mean `CRUD` is an object-level concept. No object level checks are being applied. Seems like a pretty reasonable answer to me. @RahulSharma

Answer (score 3):

PMD rule [`ApexCRUDViolation`](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd-apex/rules/apex/security.html#ApexCRUDViolationRule) is basically complaining because you're not checking object level access while performing CRUD operation.

It can be done as with adding following condition:

```
Schema.sObjectType.SchemeMaster__c.isAccessible() && 
Schema.sObjectType.PromotionMaster__c.isAccessible()
```

to your code:

```
if (Schema.sObjectType.SchemeMaster__c.isAccessible() && 
    Schema.sObjectType.PromotionMaster__c.isAccessible() && 
    Schema.sObjectType.SchemeMaster__c.fields.InterestRate__c.isAccessible() &&     
    Schema.sObjectType.PromotionMaster__c.fields.Name.isAccessible()) 
    sObj = [SELECT Name, InterestRate__c, MonthDueDate__c,
        (SELECT Id, Name FROM Promotion_Masters__r) 
        FROM SchemeMaster__c WHERE id = :lObj.Scheme__c];
    autoMap.put('SchemeMaster__c', sObj);
}
```

Note:

1. Try not to hard-code any API names if you're developing a managed package as you did in setting key of `autoMap` variable.
2. Even though now [governor limits are removed from describe calls](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_apex_describe_limit_removal.htm), try to make optimum use of it.