# Resolve PMD's ApexCRUDViolation

Tags: pmd

I'm having trouble resolving the ApexCRUDViolation for this method.

It seems similar to [this example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197627/apex-crud-violation), am I handling the fields queried via relationship correctly (e.g. ChargentOrders__Order__r.Entity__r.Name)?

```
    public List<ChargentOrders__Transaction__c> selectForZuoraHistory(String zuoraAccountId) {
        if (!Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.fields.Id.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.fields.ChargentOrders__Type__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.fields.ChargentOrders__Amount__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.fields.ChargentOrders__Payment_Method__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.fields.ChargentOrders__Gateway_Date__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.fields.Client__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.fields.ChargentOrders__Order__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.fields.CreatedDate.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.fields.ChargentOrders__Response_Status__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.fields.Date_of_Transaction__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.fields.Entity__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c.fields.Account_Bill__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.Account_Bill__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.Account_Bill__c.fields.Parent_Account__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.Account.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Zuora_Id__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Account_Number__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.Entity__c.isAccessible() ||
            !Schema.SObjectType.Entity__c.fields.Name.isAccessible()) {
            throw new Util.CustomException('Insufficient permissions');
        }
        return [
            SELECT Id,
                ChargentOrders__Type__c,
                ChargentOrders__Amount__c,
                ChargentOrders__Payment_Method__c,
                ChargentOrders__Gateway_Date__c,
                Client__r.Account_Number__c,
                ChargentOrders__Order__r.Entity__c,
                ChargentOrders__Order__r.Entity__r.Name,
                CreatedDate,
                ChargentOrders__Order__r.Account_Bill__r.Parent_Account__r.Zuora_Id__c,
                ChargentOrders__Response_Status__c
            FROM ChargentOrders__Transaction__c
            WHERE ChargentOrders__Order__r.Entity__r.Name != 'Exclude'
            AND ChargentOrders__Response_Status__c != 'Error'
            AND ChargentOrders__Order__r.Account_Bill__r.Parent_Account__r.Zuora_Id__c =: zuoraAccountId
            AND ChargentOrders__Response_Status__c != 'Declined'
            AND ChargentOrders__Amount__c != 0
            AND ChargentOrders__Amount__c != NULL
            ORDER BY Date_of_Transaction__c
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Peter, have you tried checking for "true" first? Like, instead of checking if it's not visible.. try your if with:
if (Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.isAccessible() &&
Schema.SObjectType.ChargentOrders__Transaction__c.fields.Id.isAccessible() &&...etc...
then return the query... else throw the error... Remember to replace the '||'s with '&&'s.

Comment: @RobertSösemann - this is up your alley

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys! I didn't try checking for "true", but when I did, same results.

Comment: Sorry - first time trying to comment.  It turns out that the violation goes away if I comment out the two conditions in the where clause that have a relationship field (ChargentOrders__Order__r.Entity__r.Name != 'Exclude' and ChargentOrders__Order__r.Account_Bill__r.Parent_Account__r.Zuora_Id__c =: zuoraAccountId). Since those are also being selected, I can only assume it's a bug with the rule?